# selenium - can WebDriverWait().until(myFunc) use functions outside of the WebDriver?

Tags: python, function, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to call a function outside of the WebDriver in the .until?  No matter what I try, I get the exception:

```
Exception: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'verifyObj_tag'.
```

I have a class called 'ad_selenium' and all calls to selenium are encapsulated within the library. The explicitWait function I wrote is trying to use another class method in the .until:

```
def explicitWait(self,tag_name,search_for,element=None,compare='contains',seconds=20):
    element = WebDriverWait(self.__WD, seconds).until( lambda self: \
        self.verifyObj_tag(tag_name,search_for,element=element,compare=compare))
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations of lambda functions and function varaibles like:

```
def explicitWait(self,tag_name,search_for,element=None,compare='contains',seconds=20):
    x = self.verifyObj_tag
    element = WebDriverWait(self.__WD, seconds).until( lambda x: \
        x(tag_name,search_for,element=element,compare=compare))
```

Looking at the code inside selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py, it looks like it always passes webriver to the method passed in the until:

```
def until(self, method, message=''):
    while(True):
        try:
            value = method(self._driver)   #<<--webdriver passed here
            if value:
                return value
        except self._ignored_exceptions:
            pass
```

Any ideas on how to make that work?

Comment: Could you show what is `verifyObj_tag()` and an example `explicitWait()` usage for completeness sake? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to let it pass the `driver` as an argument:

```
element = WebDriverWait(self.__WD, seconds).until(lambda driver: \
    self.verifyObj_tag(tag_name, search_for, element=element, compare=compare))
```

Comment: I thought I fully understood what I was doing but this proves that I am out of my depth here. This worked perfectly. What I don't understand is why it worked. So I defined a function variable called 'driver' but never used it in the call. Any pointers so I can fully understand how it would would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @SecondGear sure, see this `method(self._driver)` function call in `until`? `method` is our `lambda` function which is calling `verifyObj_tag` method inside - function calling function, in other words. Does it help understanding? Thanks.